# Javascript client code for a web service

Tags: javascript, html, apache, web-services

I have made a Java script client for my web service which is running on my localhost at 7788 port. The javascript client looks as given below. But I am not able to connect to the web service from the client. Can some one help me in connecting to the web service. 
P.S. I am running my java script client on apache2 server at 8080.

Java script client code:

```
<html><head> 
<title> Product Mart</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function InitializeService(){
  service.useService("http://localhost:7788/ProductMart/?wsdl", 
"ProductMart");
 }
 var nm,qnty,crdN,crdD;
 function placeOrder(){
  nm = document.DemoWS.nm.value;
  qnty = document.DemoWS.quantity.value;
  crdN = document.DemoWS.cardNum.value;
  crdD = document.DemoWS.cardDate.value;
  service.ProductMart.callService("getQuote",nm,quantity);
 }
 function ShowResult(){
alert(event.result.value);
  }
 </script>

  </head> 
 <body onload="InitializeService()" id="service" 
style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)" onresult="ShowResult()">
 <h1 style="font-family:verdana;color:blue;text-align:center;">
 Welcome to FalseSecure's Product Mart </h1>
 <br> 
 <form name="DemoWS"method="post" action="" >
  <hr>

  Product: Classmate-pen - cost: 30/- <br>
  Product: Lux-sandal-soap - cost: 52/- <br>
  Product: Lays-Krunchi - cost: 20/- <br>
  Product: Nature-cake - cost: 24/- <br>
  Product: Deodrant - cost: 130/- <br>
  <hr>
  <p> Name of the product: <input type="text" name="nm" id="nm" value=""/></p> 
  <p> Credit card number: <input type="text" name="cardNum" id="cardNum" value=""/></p> 
  <p> Credit card expiry date:<input type="text" name="cardDate" 
  id="cardDate"    value=""/></p>
  <br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="placeOrder()" /> 
  </form> 
  </body> 
  </html>
```

Console error that I am getting:

```
GET http://ads.panoramtech.net/loader.js?client=wc net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
InitializeService 
onload
```

Comment: try sending ajax requests to a php script..

Comment: By removing adblocker the first error is removed but I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function productMart.html:6
InitializeService productMart.html:6
onload

Comment: Is productmart defined somewhere else?

Comment: productMart is running on my machine on localhost at port 7788.

Comment: By the way by switching to php my problem got solved and I could successfully call my web services but I don't how to proceed in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the console error which you are getting when trying to call the service. Please go to network tab and see the response when the request is happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you see connections to ads.panoramtech.net you are probably infected with advertisment/tracking spyware. It is most likely being caused by a browser extension that you have activated. On my machine it was the ShowIp extension. Just search for ads.panoramtech.net to learn more about it.